# Tool that transforms various input files to single output format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xslt

I'm looking for a solution for a problem that seems quite common to me. But I can't find any directions.

The problem I'm having is that I receive multiple input files (xsl, xslx, csv, plain ascii) that I need to transform into one format. So I'm actually looking for a tool that can be configured to parse inputfiles and generate an outputfile in one format (preferably csv).

If such a tool doen't exist, then I will probably create one myself using Visual Studio/C#. Can anyone give me any directions to existing tools and/or C# coding examples that do similar things?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Paul

Comment: If you are seeking a tool, then you are at the wrong place.  If you are seeking help on how to program it, your question is far too open-ended.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer for an example of reading/writing CSV files. You're on your own writing logic to convert each format (xsl, xslx, ascii) into csv format.

Comment: Glad to see your answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to write a parser parsing xls to CSV with C#, a nice example can be found here

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yuanwang200409/how-to-convert-xls-file-into-csv-file-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to you question, but it may help. Here is a generalised solution for converting arbitary CSV to XML.

[CSV-to-XML](http://pascaliburnus.seanbdurkin.id.au/index.php?/archives/17-A-Generalised-and-Comprehensive-Solution-to-CSV-to-XML-and-XML-to-CSV-Transformations.html)

Comment: Thanks! This might be part of what I need.